# when create a new blob use create_blob_from_bytes method. Get Error: The specified blob does not exist. ErrorCode: Blob NotFound

Tags: python-3.x, azure-storage

when I trying to upload a new blob to the blob container, I get the "The specified blob does not exist" error.
This is very weird. I just want to create a new blob, with a new unique blob name.

The code I used are like this:
self.blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(self.container, item['id'] + '.jpg', item['data'])

Azure-Storage/2.1.0-2.1.0 (Python CPython 3.6.9; Linux 5.4.0-1031-azure)

Error Messages:

2020-11-11 08:18:45 [azure.storage.common.storageclient] INFO: Client-Request-ID=XXXXXX-9436-0017fa0372fd Receiving Response: Server-Timestamp=Wed, 11 Nov 2020 08:18:44 GMT, Server-Request-ID=XXXXXX-1703-b8cd58000000, HTTP Status Code=404, Message=The specified blob does not exist., Headers={'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'server': 'Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 'x-ms-request-id': 'XXXXXX-b8cd58000000', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'XXXXX-9436-0017fa0372fd', 'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02', 'x-ms-error-code': 'BlobNotFound', 'date': 'Wed, 11 Nov 2020 08:18:44 GMT'}.
2020-11-11 08:18:45 [azure.storage.common.storageclient] INFO: Client-Request-ID=XXXXXX6-0017fa0372fd Received expected http error: Server-Timestamp=Wed, 11 Nov 2020 08:18:44 GMT, Server-Request-ID=XXXXXX3-b8cd58000000, HTTP status code=404, Exception=The specified blob does not exist. ErrorCode: BlobNotFound.
2020-11-11 08:18:45 [azure.storage.common.storageclient] INFO: Client-Request-ID=XXXXXXX-9436-0017fa0372fd Outgoing request: Method=PUT, Path=/xxxxx-images-int/fd4e0a863575d6ebe26b14d0c655c4ba.jpg, Query={'timeout': None}, Headers={'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob', 'x-ms-lease-id': None, 'If-Modified-Since': None, 'If-Unmodified-Since': None, 'If-Match': None, 'If-None-Match': None, 'x-ms-access-tier': None, 'Content-Length': '101445', 'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02', 'User-Agent': 'Azure-Storage/2.1.0-2.1.0 (Python CPython 3.6.9; Linux 5.4.0-1031-azure)', 'x-ms-client-request-id': 'xxxxxxxxxxb-9436-0017fa0372fd', 'x-ms-date': 'Wed, 11 Nov 2020 08:18:45 GMT', 'Authorization': 'REDACTED'}.

Answer (score 0):

install:

`pip install azure-storage-blob`

import:

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient
```

code:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name = "test"
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, "MyFirstBlob.txt")
blob_client.upload_blob(somestream, blob_type="BlockBlob")
```

Above code works fine on my side, please have a try.

Comment: @qing Are you sure you show the right moudle version? I didn't find this version. https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage/ And this package is very old, the official API recommends using azure-storage-blob.

Comment: @qing 'Starting with v0.37.0, this package is deprecated. Please install the service specific packages prefixed by azure-storage needed for your application.' -- from the document.

Comment: The current Azure-Storage version of my code is 2.1.0. It does not have the BlobServiceClient but BlockBlobService. And my code works fine before, but after I updated some of the python modules, it starts to produce the error. Your code with a higher version of azures.storage.blob works fine. thank you.

Comment: @qing Maybe the modules conflict. Can you show the link of Azure-Storage 2.1.0? I will do a test.

Comment: I used the `pip install azure-storage==2.1.0` to install the 2.1.0 version of azure.storage